# In Plotly 3D Scatterplot, is there a way to freeze rotation of one axis?

Tags: python, plotly

I am making a 3-D Scatterplot with plotly in Python 3 and the Z-axis represents time. I would like to freeze that so that, when the using clicks around to rotate the plot, it spins on that axis, but that axis stays up and down. I'm not sure if it's possible, but that would be a great feature.

As it is, the oldest points are at the top (this is a genetic tree) and the newest are at the bottom. However, it's very easy to get this turned when clicking around the plot to rotate and then the time axis is going left-to-right or diagonal or something and it's a bit disorienting, especially for people who are not used to looking at complex visuals like this (i.e. my intended audience).

A first draft example: https://plot.ly/~seth127/6

Any help is greatly appreciated! 
Thanks,
Seth

Comment: I believe this is the attribute that's relevant to you: https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-dragmode